# Как правильно сделать запрос по условию с датой к БД в Java (JDBC)

Tags: java, java-ee

Вопрос состоит в том что я хочу правильно оформить запрос, да бы не допустить в будущем SQL-инъекций но что-то не получается, помогите разобраться, делаю следующим образом:

```
String query="Select * from tab where date  between to_date(? , 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi') and to_date('17.10.17 7:00', 'dd.mm.yy HH24:mi')"   
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);    
String test = "'" + datestart +" 22:00'";     
ps.setString(1, test);    
resultSets= ps.executeQuery(query);

while (resultSets.next())
{
 Roll roll = new Roll();    
 roll.setNumbern(resultSets.getInt(1));    
 roll.setRollnum(resultSets.getInt(3));    
 roll.setShift(resultSets.getInt(20));
}
```

Ну и наполняю List нужными мне данными для отображения. Но запрос не проходит, получаю ошибку:

> Exception : ORA-03115: неподдерживаемый сетевой тип данных или
>   представление данных

Либо

> Exception : ORA-01858: вместо ожидаемой цифры обнаружен нецифровой
>   символ

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Чем в результате равняется переменная `test` ? И добавьте тег `Oracle`

Comment: @lDrakonl Добрый день. Вот чем  `'16.10.2017 22:00'` как бы все соблюдено вроде бы ?

Comment: А если сразу в запрос вписать нужную дату, он отрабатывает корректно?

Comment: @lDrakonl Да конечно. Изначально отладка запроса была с вписанными данными. Затем я решил сделать по уму вроде как, да и дату мне нужно передавать с веб формы в сервлет

Comment: @lDrakonl Даже если вписать `String test = "'16.10.2017 22:00'";` всеравно ошибка `ORA-01858`

Comment: Похоже на то, что при добавлении текста в запрос апострофа ставить не надо. Попробуйте убрать апостроф (`'`)

Comment: @lDrakonl Да вы были правы нужно убрать `'` одинарные ковычки. Оформите пожалуйста как ответ и я закрою тему. Большое вам спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для метода `setString` интерфейса `PreparedStatement`не надо добавлять апостроф (`'`) в строку.

Замените

```
String test = "'" + datestart +" 22:00'";
```

на

```
String test = "datestart +" 22:00";
```

и код заработает.